# parsing a json received from stanbol containing relationships

Tags: java, json, apache-stanbol

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "comment": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment",
    "confidence": {
      "@id": "http://fise.iks-project.eu/ontology/confidence",
      "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double"
    },
    "created": {
      "@id": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/created",
      "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime"
    },
    "creator": {
      "@id": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/creator",
      "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    },
    "depiction": {
      "@id": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/depiction",
      "@type": "@id"
    },
    "end": {
      "@id": "http://fise.iks-project.eu/ontology/end",
      "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int"
    },
    "Enhancement": "http://fise.iks-project.eu/ontology/Enhancement",
    "entity-label": "http://fise.iks-project.eu/ontology/entity-label",
    "entity-reference": {
      "@id": "http://fise.iks-project.eu/ontology/entity-reference",
      "@type": "@id"
    },
    "EntityAnnotation": "http://fise.iks-project.eu/ontology/EntityAnnotation",
    "entityRank": {
      "@id": "http://stanbol.apache.org/ontology/entityhub/entityhub#entityRank",
      "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float"
    },
    "extracted-from": {
      "@id": "http://fise.iks-project.eu/ontology/extracted-from",
      "@type": "@id"
    },
    "label": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label",
    "language": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/language",
    "LinguisticSystem": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/LinguisticSystem",
    "Person": "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person",
    "relation": {
      "@id": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/relation",
      "@type": "@id"
    },
    "score": {
      "@id": "http://stanbol.apache.org/ontology/entityhub/query#score",
      "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float"
    },
    "selected-text": "http://fise.iks-project.eu/ontology/selected-text",
    "selection-context": "http://fise.iks-project.eu/ontology/selection-context",
    "site": "http://stanbol.apache.org/ontology/entityhub/entityhub#site",
    "start": {
      "@id": "http://fise.iks-project.eu/ontology/start",
      "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int"
    },
    "TextAnnotation": "http://fise.iks-project.eu/ontology/TextAnnotation",
    "type": {
      "@id": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/type",
      "@type": "@id"
    },
    "xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Christian",
      "comment": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "A Christian (is a person who adheres to Christianity, an Abrahamic, monotheistic religion based on the life and teachings of Jesus of Nazareth as recorded in the Canonical gospels and the letters of the New Testament. \"Christian\" derives from the Koine Greek word Christ, a translation of the Biblical Hebrew term Messiah."
      },
      "depiction": [
        "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/11/Santuário_de_Fátima_modified.jpg",
        "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/40/Famous_Christians.jpg",
        "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/BegaPrayer.jpg",
        "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/Bloch-SermonOnTheMount.jpg",
        "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Santuário_de_Fátima_modified.jpg/200px-Santuário_de_Fátima_modified.jpg",
        "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/40/Famous_Christians.jpg/200px-Famous_Christians.jpg",
        "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/BegaPrayer.jpg/200px-BegaPrayer.jpg",
        "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/96/Bloch-SermonOnTheMount.jpg/200px-Bloch-SermonOnTheMount.jpg"
      ],
      "entityRank": 0.71846753,
      "label": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "Christian"
      },
      "score": 17.521954
    },
    {
      "@id": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Thursday",
      "comment": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "Thursday is the fourth or fifth day of the week. According to the ISO 8601 international standard adopted in most western countries, it is the fourth day of the week. In most of the world, countries use the Sunday-first convention and it is defined as the fifth day of the week. It is the fifth day of the week in the Judeo-Christian calendar as well, and was defined so in the ancient Mesopotamian and biblical calendars. It falls between Wednesday and Friday."
      },
      "depiction": [
        "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Thor.jpg",
        "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/23/Thor.jpg/200px-Thor.jpg"
      ],
      "entityRank": 0.40759254,
      "label": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "Thursday"
      },
      "score": 1.9757141
    },
    {
      "@id": "urn:enhancement-1a2ffccb-5f8c-2743-803b-3581b9af8bf8",
      "@type": [
        "Enhancement",
        "EntityAnnotation"
      ],
      "confidence": 0.80999994,
      "created": "2013-07-11T19:44:44.827Z",
      "creator": "org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.engines.entitylinking.engine.EntityLinkingEngine",
      "entity-label": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "Christians"
      },
      "entity-reference": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Christian",
      "extracted-from": "urn:content-item-sha1-8a5c1ec376eec1d1f0ca4567c920100eac62c44e",
      "relation": "urn:enhancement-59dcea1a-0f7d-a7b6-6a38-031e76794ad7",
      "site": "dbpedia"
    },
    {
      "@id": "urn:enhancement-2921ff7f-d1d9-b32d-8624-b8ea01b2ea48",
      "@type": [
        "Enhancement",
        "EntityAnnotation"
      ],
      "confidence": 0.79012346,
      "created": "2013-07-11T19:44:44.827Z",
      "creator": "org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.engines.entitylinking.engine.EntityLinkingEngine",
      "entity-label": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "Thursdays"
      },
      "entity-reference": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Thursday",
      "extracted-from": "urn:content-item-sha1-8a5c1ec376eec1d1f0ca4567c920100eac62c44e",
      "relation": "urn:enhancement-f5f80742-e71b-718f-ead9-753aa145b5ff",
      "site": "dbpedia"
    },
    {
      "@id": "urn:enhancement-2fe7fd43-bb49-3667-ab1f-63a0936ede7f",
      "@type": [
        "Enhancement",
        "TextAnnotation"
      ],
      "confidence": 0.999996,
      "created": "2013-07-11T19:44:44.795Z",
      "creator": "org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.engines.langdetect.LanguageDetectionEnhancementEngine",
      "extracted-from": "urn:content-item-sha1-8a5c1ec376eec1d1f0ca4567c920100eac62c44e",
      "language": "en",
      "type": "LinguisticSystem"
    },
    {
      "@id": "urn:enhancement-59dcea1a-0f7d-a7b6-6a38-031e76794ad7",
      "@type": [
        "Enhancement",
        "TextAnnotation"
      ],
      "confidence": 1.0,
      "created": "2013-07-11T19:44:44.827Z",
      "creator": "org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.engines.entitylinking.engine.EntityLinkingEngine",
      "end": 56,
      "extracted-from": "urn:content-item-sha1-8a5c1ec376eec1d1f0ca4567c920100eac62c44e",
      "selected-text": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "Christian"
      },
      "selection-context": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "ed a Christian uni"
      },
      "start": 47
    },
    {
      "@id": "urn:enhancement-5f9962d4-cc34-86ed-27cc-2db4c96506f4",
      "@type": [
        "Enhancement",
        "EntityAnnotation"
      ],
      "confidence": 1.0,
      "created": "2013-07-11T19:44:44.826Z",
      "creator": "org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.engines.entitylinking.engine.EntityLinkingEngine",
      "entity-label": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "President Barack Obama"
      },
      "entity-reference": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Presidency_of_Barack_Obama",
      "extracted-from": "urn:content-item-sha1-8a5c1ec376eec1d1f0ca4567c920100eac62c44e",
      "relation": "urn:enhancement-837e5beb-6e54-3947-fffa-b619c22845b0",
      "site": "dbpedia"
    },
    {
      "@id": "urn:enhancement-710fe84c-108b-6964-6242-a0379b54c1c3",
      "@type": [
        "Enhancement",
        "EntityAnnotation"
      ],
      "confidence": 1.0,
      "created": "2013-07-11T19:44:44.827Z",
      "creator": "org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.engines.entitylinking.engine.EntityLinkingEngine",
      "entity-label": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "Christian"
      },
      "entity-reference": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Christian",
      "extracted-from": "urn:content-item-sha1-8a5c1ec376eec1d1f0ca4567c920100eac62c44e",
      "relation": "urn:enhancement-59dcea1a-0f7d-a7b6-6a38-031e76794ad7",
      "site": "dbpedia"
    },
    {
      "@id": "urn:enhancement-837e5beb-6e54-3947-fffa-b619c22845b0",
      "@type": [
        "Enhancement",
        "TextAnnotation"
      ],
      "confidence": 1.0,
      "created": "2013-07-11T19:44:44.826Z",
      "creator": "org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.engines.entitylinking.engine.EntityLinkingEngine",
      "end": 133,
      "extracted-from": "urn:content-item-sha1-8a5c1ec376eec1d1f0ca4567c920100eac62c44e",
      "selected-text": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "President Barack Obama"
      },
      "selection-context": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "t of President Barack Obama's 2"
      },
      "start": 111
    },
    {
      "@id": "urn:enhancement-a7618904-adc4-f20c-0942-15b63affa456",
      "@type": [
        "Enhancement",
        "EntityAnnotation"
      ],
      "confidence": 1.0,
      "created": "2013-07-11T19:44:44.827Z",
      "creator": "org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.engines.entitylinking.engine.EntityLinkingEngine",
      "entity-label": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "Thursday"
      },
      "entity-reference": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Thursday",
      "extracted-from": "urn:content-item-sha1-8a5c1ec376eec1d1f0ca4567c920100eac62c44e",
      "relation": "urn:enhancement-f5f80742-e71b-718f-ead9-753aa145b5ff",
      "site": "dbpedia"
    },
    {
      "@id": "urn:enhancement-bd5d020c-0685-74d4-a26a-1d504c406bc8",
      "@type": [
        "Enhancement",
        "EntityAnnotation"
      ],
      "confidence": 0.75,
      "created": "2013-07-11T19:44:44.826Z",
      "creator": "org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.engines.entitylinking.engine.EntityLinkingEngine",
      "entity-label": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "President Barack Hussein Obama"
      },
      "entity-reference": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barack_Obama",
      "extracted-from": "urn:content-item-sha1-8a5c1ec376eec1d1f0ca4567c920100eac62c44e",
      "relation": "urn:enhancement-837e5beb-6e54-3947-fffa-b619c22845b0",
      "site": "dbpedia"
    },
    {
      "@id": "urn:enhancement-ca172daa-8c72-810b-07e8-99f123cce395",
      "@type": [
        "Enhancement",
        "TextAnnotation"
      ],
      "confidence": 0.88367766,
      "created": "2013-07-11T19:44:44.815Z",
      "creator": "org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.engines.opennlp.impl.NamedEntityExtractionEnhancementEngine",
      "end": 133,
      "extracted-from": "urn:content-item-sha1-8a5c1ec376eec1d1f0ca4567c920100eac62c44e",
      "selected-text": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "Barack Obama"
      },
      "selection-context": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "A federal appeals court on Thursday rejected a Christian university's religion-based challenge against part of President Barack Obama's 2010 healthcare overhaul, which the school claimed had forced taxpayers and employers to subsidize abortions and contraception."
      },
      "start": 121,
      "type": "Person"
    },
    {
      "@id": "urn:enhancement-e6aff5ba-1089-2d0e-763c-30a2347663c7",
      "@type": [
        "Enhancement",
        "EntityAnnotation"
      ],
      "confidence": 0.77049375,
      "created": "2013-07-11T19:44:44.826Z",
      "creator": "org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.engines.entitylinking.engine.EntityLinkingEngine",
      "entity-label": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "President barack obama"
      },
      "entity-reference": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barack_Obama",
      "extracted-from": "urn:content-item-sha1-8a5c1ec376eec1d1f0ca4567c920100eac62c44e",
      "relation": "urn:enhancement-837e5beb-6e54-3947-fffa-b619c22845b0",
      "site": "dbpedia"
    },
    {
      "@id": "urn:enhancement-f5f80742-e71b-718f-ead9-753aa145b5ff",
      "@type": [
        "Enhancement",
        "TextAnnotation"
      ],
      "confidence": 1.0,
      "created": "2013-07-11T19:44:44.826Z",
      "creator": "org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.engines.entitylinking.engine.EntityLinkingEngine",
      "end": 35,
      "extracted-from": "urn:content-item-sha1-8a5c1ec376eec1d1f0ca4567c920100eac62c44e",
      "selected-text": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "Thursday"
      },
      "selection-context": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "t on Thursday rej"
      },
      "start": 27
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't have to use '@context'. Only '@graph' is needed. Now inside '@graph' there are several arrays and I need to find the value of 'entity-reference' from the array which contains it (not all arrays have it). Now the array which will have this 'entity-reference' key will also have a 'relation' key using which I have to search the array whose '@id' key has value equal to 'relation' then from that array I again need to find a key.

Example:

This array contains key 'entity-reference' and 'relation':

```
    {
      "@id": "urn:enhancement-e6aff5ba-1089-2d0e-763c-30a2347663c7",
      "@type": [
        "Enhancement",
        "EntityAnnotation"
      ],
      "confidence": 0.77049375,
      "created": "2013-07-11T19:44:44.826Z",
      "creator": "org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.engines.entitylinking.engine.EntityLinkingEngine",
      "entity-label": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "President barack obama"
      },
      "entity-reference": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barack_Obama",
      "extracted-from": "urn:content-item-sha1-8a5c1ec376eec1d1f0ca4567c920100eac62c44e",
      "relation": "urn:enhancement-837e5beb-6e54-3947-fffa-b619c22845b0",
      "site": "dbpedia"
    }
```

From this I will extract `"entity-reference": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barack_Obama"` and then will search for array whose '@id' is `"relation": "urn:enhancement-837e5beb-6e54-3947-fffa-b619c22845b0"`

which is:

```
    {
      "@id": "urn:enhancement-837e5beb-6e54-3947-fffa-b619c22845b0",
      "@type": [
        "Enhancement",
        "TextAnnotation"
      ],
      "confidence": 1.0,
      "created": "2013-07-11T19:44:44.826Z",
      "creator": "org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.engines.entitylinking.engine.EntityLinkingEngine",
      "end": 133,
      "extracted-from": "urn:content-item-sha1-8a5c1ec376eec1d1f0ca4567c920100eac62c44e",
      "selected-text": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "President Barack Obama"
      },
      "selection-context": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "t of President Barack Obama's 2"
      },
      "start": 111
    }
```

So do I have this kind search kind facility with JSON?

Comment: you should parse your json in a pojo, then apply your business rules !! visit json.org for parsing techniques.

Comment: @Sikorski: the thing is not only parsing it also involves a bit of searching